# In V8 why does Isolate::GetCurrent() return NULL?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, v8, libv8

I have compiled [V8](https://code.google.com/p/v8/) on Ubuntu and have a very simple V8 program called isolate_test.cc. It is based on the [Hello World example from Google](https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started):

```
#include <v8.h> 
using namespace v8;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    V8::initialize();
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent(); //Always returns NULL

    return 0; 
}
```

The command I use to compile this program is:

```
g++ -Iinclude -g isolate_test.cc -o isolate_test -Wl,--start-group out/x64.debug/obj.target/{tools/gyp/libv8_{base,snapshot},third_party/icu/libicu{uc,i18n,data}}.a -Wl,--end-group -lrt -lpthread
```

Problem is [`Isolate::GetCurrent()`](https://code.google.com/p/v8/codesearch#v8/trunk/src/api.cc&q=Isolate::GetCurrent%28%29&sq=package:v8&l=6523) always returns `NULL`. Why does this happen and what is the correct way of getting the current `Isolate`?

I could be way off track but my first thought is that this relates to `Isolate::GetCurrent()` being unable to get the current thread from `libpthread`.

**Update:** As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924087/segfault-in-v8-on-windows-in-handlescope-constructor) I have added `V8::initialize()` as the first call in the program, however this does not solve the problem.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924087/segfault-in-v8-on-windows-in-handlescope-constructor , you're probably missing a call to V8::initialize(); , which is probably also a documentation bug in the examples

Comment: I can't find any reference to `V8::initialize()` - has it been removed from the API?

Comment: Not entirely sure, though it's defined in the file of your link to [Isolate::GetCurrent()](https://code.google.com/p/v8/codesearch#v8/trunk/src/api.cc&q=Isolate%3a%3aGetCurrent%28%29&sq=package%3av8&l=6523)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue. I don't really know the underlying reason, but NULL here means default isolate was not created and entered. The obvious workaround is to do it manually

```
Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent(); // returns NULL
if (!isolate) {
    isolate = Isolate::New();
    isolate->Enter();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The default isolate has been removed from v8. As a result, `GetCurrent()` is no longer initialized by default.

Here's the issue for the change: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=359977